# Where Complex Results and NULLS - SQL C#

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in the database with a textbox that brings me from another field if there is a record but I want it to bring me a null when it does not exist in the base

```
SELECT [restaurantes]
    
      ,[ubicacion]
   
  FROM [col].[dbo].[bog]
  where restaurantes in ('colombia','bogota')
```

and result is this :

```
restaurantes - ubicacion
colombia   -  norte_espa
```

and not get bogota because not have register in database i need restaurant and ubicacion i need show null

result :

```
restaurantes - ubicacion
colombia - norte_espa
bogota - Null or Not exists that register
```

its possible ?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: this used in my app with C# winforms  in datagridview and datatable this is my query with textbox WHERE restaurantes in ("+textBox1.Text+ ") and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `string_split()` in concert with a `Left Join`

**Example**

```
Select restaurantes = a.value
      ,B.[ubicacion]
 From  string_split('colombia,bogota',',') A
 Left Join [col].[dbo].[bog] B
        on A.value = B.restaurantes
```

Update Lower Version of SQL Server

```
Declare @List varchar(max) = 'colombia,bogota'

Select restaurantes = a.RetVal
      ,B.[ubicacion]
  From  (
        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@List,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
       ) A
 Left Join [col].[dbo].[bog] B
        on A.RetVal = B.restaurantes
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid object name 'string_split'. get this error

Comment: 2019 sql server used :: The text Bogota does not exist in the database I want it to appear in the results Bogota and in the section location null or that does not exist, to be able to identify which cities are not registered in the database

Comment: @ryuzdev Nope - you might be using SSMS version 2019 but your database server instance is clearly much earlier version.

Comment: ahhh ok ok instance server sorry is this SQL server 2005

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a `VALUES` clause as the driving row, along with a `LEFT JOIN`**

```sql
SELECT v.[restaurantes]
      ,b.[ubicacion]
FROM (VALUES
  ('colombia'),
  ('bogota')
) v(restaurantes)
LEFT JOIN [col].[dbo].[bog] b ON b.restaurantes = v.restaurantes;
```

For very old versions of SQL Server which do not support `VALUES` you can use `UNION ALL` in a subquery

```sql
SELECT v.[restaurantes]
      ,b.[ubicacion]
FROM (
    SELECT 'colombia' AS restaurantes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bogota'
) v
LEFT JOIN [col].[dbo].[bog] b ON b.restaurantes = v.restaurantes;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'. dam bro

Comment: 2005 Does not support VALUES.  Also I assumed OP wanted a more fluid approach.  Either way +1

Comment: @ryuzdev OK given you a solution for that also